# Can we stop MS Word from changing the font when I toggle the keyboard language?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, language

I'm in Windows 10 with Word 2013.
Among other challenges lately with multiple languages in Windows 10, this specific one would be great to address.

Whenever I toggle the keyboard language - for me it's between English and Chinese - Word automatically changes the font.
This happens immediately, when I toggle.  It's not a question of font substitution for something unusual I typed.

> **edit---**
>   I'm starting to think it is a font choice issue.   I'm trying to use
>   Microsoft Jhenghei UI, which seems designed as a Chinese font.
>   But
>   now I did try another Chinese font - Microsoft Yahei UI - and this
>   solves the problem.
>
> Can anyone confirm (links?) my problem is
>   expected behavior for a font not recognized as "Asian" ?
>
> **edit (2)**
>   Ok, digging even deeper, I'm seeing more specifically is it Traditional vs. Simplified character use.....
>    are fonts designated - according to Word - as detailed as:
>    Asian-Chinese-Simplified
>    Asian-Chinese-Traditional
>
> and my choice is rejected because my keyboard is inputting Simplified and Jhenghei is designated Traditional  (though it certainly works for Simplified)
>    ?

.
I am already using my preferred Chinese font (I think the latin letters in it are excellent).  So it isn't a question of not having the Chinese characters available - or shouldn't be.

Is there any way to just stop the change?
Or if not, can I set the target font it changes to?

Comment: Does making a Word template or templates with specified fonts for your most-often used styleshelp?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  I doubt it.  I do already have styles specified.  I went through and already changed the font in all the basic Styles, and I set the Theme fonts.  These fonts seem to be present according to the Themes.....  but it goes off-theme.   The issue seems to be that the language toggle to Chinese pulls it off-theme.   (it also exhibits the behavior of changing to a different theme because I changed language, but it isn't using that theme either.....  it's just forcing SimSun.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on probing and on learning more about fonts in Windows, I think I can reliably explain what's going on.
But I don't have any direct comments about this behavior from anywhere, which I would still welcome.

---

I'm seeing Word is aware of fonts as not only Asian but in fact Chinese and whether or not they are recommended for Simplified or Traditional characters.
This information is included inside fonts as part of a number of header tables (encoded in a binary format... need a tool to view...  which I can't find for *Microsoft* fonts yet :/).

For an example of font file informaion, here is a (detailed, technical) reference to TrueType fonts, from Microsoft Typography (.doc file):  http://www.microsoft.com/typography/tt/tt_open/msdn/ttoch02.doc.  Check out "Naming Table" on page 47 for target language info specifically.

'
You can see this intended-language info really easy, though - at least in Windows 10 - because it's right there in the Fonts folder:

[image]

'
* The Windows keyboard language certainly is specific to Simplified or Traditional.
* If I use a Simplified keyboard and set my Word Theme Font to a font marked Traditional, I have this problem.
* If I use a Simplified keyboard and set my Word Theme Font to a font marked Simplified, I don't have this problem.
* If I use a Traditional keyboard and set my Word Theme Font to a font marked Traditional, I don't have this problem.

'

- So, I don't know a way to stop the Font change and always use whatever font you prefer.
- **But the workaround exists to set the Theme Asian fonts to ones explicitly marked Simplified if using a Simplified input keyboard.  Then Word allows it and you won't experience an interruption.**
  You can see this marking by opening the Windows\Fonts folder.